# Nginx Forward All Traffic on All Ports Except Port 80

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, forwarding, godaddy

I have a domain name, let's say `example.com` registered in Dynadot. I'm having it, along with subdomains `www.example.com` and `cloud.example.com` point to my IP address via A records. I have set up some servers that are accessible using this domain name. For example, my FTP server can be accessed using `example.com:21`. I have a Node.js server running on port 80, and a [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) server running on port 85. The last thing I have set up is an Nginx server, which listens on port 80. Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cloud.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:85;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.31;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.31;
    }
}
```

What this configuration does is:

- If a user goes to `example.com` or `www.example.com`, it redirects them to my Node.js server.
- If a user goes to `cloud.example.com`, it redirects them to my Nextcloud server, which is also accessible from `example.com:85`.
- If a user wants to connect to another server running on a different port, they can use `example.com:<port>`

This works great, but my only problem is that **my ISP blocks inbound traffic for port 80!**

I tried to find a workaround for hours, and my only option is to use GoDaddy. I can host my Nginx server on GoDaddy, which points `example.com` and `www.example.com` to my Node.js server and points `cloud.example.com` to my Nextcloud server. This would work, but it means that `example.com`'s DNS settings would need to be changed to an A record pointing to the GoDaddy servers. This would all work fine, but it means that I can no longer access any of my other servers, such as my FTP server because `exmaple.com:21` would no longer point to `<my IP>:21`, but `<GoDaddy Server IP>:21`.

I was thinking, to solve this issue, I could configure my Nginx server so that it does what it did before, but if a user goes to `example.com` with ANY port other than port 80, it will forward the connection to `<my IP>:<port>`. That way, all my other servers, such as my FTP server will still be accessible through `exmaple.com:21`, but port 80 will not be blocked because the Nginx server which uses port 80 is being hosted on GoDaddy.

I don't know if this is possible with Nginx, though. If it is, what would the configuration look like? If it isn't, what other options do I have? (Other than buying my ISP's business plan to unblock port 80)

Comment: offtopic: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User,

Comment: You should not use FTP, it is a security risk.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Why even mention that? In my question, an FTP server was just an example. Off-topic comment.

Comment: Providing solid security advice is always on-topic.